# Magento: Check if compare list is empty

Tags: php, magento

I create a link in my store to compare list, but i want to display this button only if have products in compare list.

this is the following code i'm using to show the link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index'); ?>" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Google', 'width=980,height=700')" target="_blank">Abrir Compadores</a>
```

Comment: An what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do is:

```
<a <?php if(false) echo "style='display:none'"; ?> href=<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index'); ?>">Click</a>
```

in if condition of above code you can use you validation whatever condition you want to use...

Answer (score 0):

use below code to solve your problem.

```
<a class="top-compare" style="color: #003d66;" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index') ?>"><?php echo $this->__("Compare") ?></a>

<?php 
$compare = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount();
if($compare > 0){ 
//do somthing
}else{
//do anything
}
```